# Formatting column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to insert the pipe character | in a column to separate two sections of the output. Is there a way to put one in every row of a column as long as there is data in that row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select   column1, 
         column2,
         case 
           when column3 is not null 
           then '|' 
           else '' 
         end
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Not one that works one every column. You will have to repeat it for every column.

Something like this;

`SELECT CASE col IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT('|', col) END CASE FROM Table`